# Considering storing the value in a temporary variable (UI.graphic.color)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm trying to change the alpha of multiple UI elements.

"UnityEngine.UI.Graphic.color Considering storing the value in a temporary variable"

```
public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour {     
public Text nameText;
public Text dialogueText;
public Image facePlate;
public PlayerController thePlayer;

void Awake () {
    thePlayer = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController> ();
}

void Update () {

    if (!thePlayer.isTalking) {
        Color temp = facePlate.color;
        temp.a = 0f;
        nameText.color.a = temp.a;
        dialogueText.color.a = temp.a;
        facePlate.color.a = temp.a;
    }
```

I've tried multiple ways of doing this although I always end up with this same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to change the any variable of Color directly. So instead you can assign the value of your Color struct to a temp variable and change it. Then reassign the temp to the color part. Here we are each time basically taking value of the color variable and modifying it and reassigning the new value

```
if (!thePlayer.isTalking) {
    Color temp = facePlate.color;
    temp.a = 0f;
    facePlate.color = temp;

    temp = nameText.color;
    temp.a = 0f;
    nameText.color = temp;

    temp = dialogueText.color;
    temp.a = 0f;
    dialogueText.color = temp;
}
```